# Why am I getting this error on Python File "<stdin>", line 2 /n new_squares.append(squares[i]) /n ^ IndentationError: expected an indented block?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to python, and I just learned about "While Loops" So I'm trying this code which consists on copying the value of a list into another list

```
>>> squares=['red','red','red','blue','red','red']
>>> new_squares=[];
>>> i=0
>>> while(squares[i]=='red')
... new_squares.append(squares[i])
```

And now is when the error occurs

```
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    new_squares.append(squares[i])
              ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Why is this happening, I used the same code they do in the course, I just changed the value from 'orange' to 'red'

Answer (score 1):

A `while` statement should end with `:`, thus you should change

```
while(squares[i]=='red')
```

to

```
while(squares[i]=='red'):
```

and then write the following code `new_squares.append(squares[i])` at one level of indentation to the right